# VS Code: Start debugger in custom container

Tags: debugging, gdb, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a custom shell command which starts a docker container in which I run my C++ application. In VS Code, I want to configure launch.json so that when I run the configuration, it first calls my custom command to start the container and start a debugger inside the container.

Is this something possible in VS Code?

I tried to start the container as a preLaunchTask but then the debugger does not launch because it keeps waiting for the preLaunch task to finish (The preLaunch task should finish before debugger finishes since it is the container)

Comment: I have a similar need...I just want to specify an opaque shell script to execute...after that, the debugging can assume there will be gdbserver to attach to on a given port. Seems not conceptually difficult.